# Twilio Queue Cleanup

Tags: c#, twilio

I have a scenario where I need to connect an inbound caller with another party, selected dynamically.  The logic to select, and connect the 3rd party can take a little time to execute as it involves some additional back-end systems, so I want to `<Enqueue />` the original caller while I make the outbound call - this way they get hold music!

When I enqueue the original caller I generate a `Guid::NewGuid()` for the queue name to ensure they are the only person in it.

All the call flow logic is under control, but I've noticed that I have a lot of queues now that I'll never use again.

Do I need to clean these up as part of my call script? Does Twilio clean them up automatically after some period of inactivity? Is there a cost, or practical limit to the number of queues that I can have at any time?

The doco on the Twilio site is a little thin on this subject - does anyone know? Or have a better mechanism maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Based on how you describe your app, its sounds like instead of using `<Queue>`, you could drop the incoming callers into a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference).  Using Conference you can still give them wait music while your app goes to connect to the right agent, but since conferences automatically go away once the last caller leaves, there is no need for you to clean them up after.

Also, have you looked at using [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/taskrouter) to help you route those calls to the right agent?  Using TaskRouter you can drop the [inbound call directly into a TaskQueue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/taskrouter/create-tasks) while the correct agent is identified based on attributes that you define and becomes available.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not that kind of "Agent" - I have to outbound dial third parties and go hunting for someone.

I had avoided Conference because they attract an additional cost for no apparent benefit, and I am forced to use "global" conferencing because all my users are in Australia and it seems wrong to conference everyone via the US.

You've not really answered the question though - do the Queues get cleaned up? Do they need to be? If not, is there a limit on how many I can have?

Answer (score 0):

Another Twilio developer evangelist here. :)

In answer to your question, you have nothing to worry about with your Queues. When there are no calls left in a Queue it will get cleaned up on our side, so you have nothing to worry about on your side.

**Edit**

I was wrong, Queues will not get cleared up automatically. Ideally in this situation where a queue only gets used once for a single user, the queue would then be deleted via the API. However, there are no limits on the number of queues you can have and being unable to delete a queue in a certain situation would not cause problems.

Comment: Um, bad news, I've done some more digging internally and apparently I was wrong. The best thing in your case would be to delete the queue once you've dequeued the caller with a delete call to the REST API. I'm on my phone right now, but will write up a different answer for this when I have a proper computer. Sorry to mislead you.

Comment: Well OK then what happens if I don't/can't (there are cases where I will lose control and, perhaps, be unable to cleanup properly)? There doesn't seem to be any billing associated with this, nor is there any documentation suggesting limits? Will the system just stop provisioning new queues at some point?

Comment: Hey @RichardHauer, I've had a chat with the team that work on this. There is no charge for you having multiple queues and no real limits if you don't delete them. Queues do create an item in our database, so it would be nice if you could delete a queue once you are done with it, however, as I said, it's not going to cause you a problem if you are unable to do so.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  Since talking about this we switched the setup to a fixed pool of about 300 queues.  This works because we discovered that you can dequeue an individual caller who isn't necessarily first in the queue.  That means we can stack people into one queue without needing to worry about incorrectly connecting people.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a better solution. Glad it's sorted now.